# Does the Boost testing framework support test dependencies?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, boost-test

One of my favorite unit testing frameworks is [PHPUnit](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/index.html) because it supports test dependencies (i.e. the ability to mark tests as dependent upon other tests, running the dependent tests conditionally on the success of their dependencies).  I've been using the [Boost testing framework](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html) more recently to test my C++ code, and while it suits most of my unit testing needs, it doesn't appear to support test dependencies.

I've scoured the documentation for the Boost testing framework and have found [various](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/depends-on-question-td2707306.html) [hints](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boost-list/MtcvrVP0uXg) that Boost supports this feature, but I've yet to find a documentation page or any concrete examples of test dependency support in Boost.  Are the previously given pages red herrings, or does the Boost testing framework actually support test dependencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you've found yourself that the feature is there and according to the links, it's there for end user to use.
It's not documented by accident and "should be added soon" (as per links).

Now, here's a nother post I've found which uses feature:
http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Unit-Test-Framework-strange-behaviour-of-test-unit-depends-on-td2653654.html

Sample from there (unfortunately, looks like no BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE works there).
Also note that **code is incorrect** because `Dependency()` is never called and therefore dependent test doesn't run as well.

```
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

using boost::unit_test::test_suite;

void Dependency()
{
  BOOST_MESSAGE( "Dependency!" );
  BOOST_CHECK( 1 );
}

void TC_TestCase()
{
  BOOST_MESSAGE( "A test case!" );
  BOOST_CHECK( 1 );
}

test_suite*
init_unit_test_suite( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  test_suite* ts = BOOST_TEST_SUITE( "Test_Test" );

  ts->add( BOOST_TEST_CASE( &TC_TestCase ) );

/*1*/  ts->depends_on( BOOST_TEST_CASE( &Dependency ) );

  return ts;
}
```

**Update**

Performed some experimenting and here's an example with automatic test/suits and dependencies. 
Some notes about code:

1. Boost here is 1.42, there may be slight differences for newer versions.
2. If you put `test_suite2` after `test_suite1` in the cpp file, keeping dependencies the same, test_suite1 will be always skipped because `test_suite2` is not run before it.
3. I made `test_case4` to fail so that `test_suite1` is skipped, but if `test_case4` succeeds, `test_suite1` does execute.
4. I'm pretty sure you'll be able to make dependencies registration much prettier and shorter.

The code:

```
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
using namespace boost::unit_test;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(test_suite2)
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_case4)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(false);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(test_suite1)
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_case1) 
{ 
    BOOST_CHECK(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_case2) 
{
    BOOST_CHECK(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()


//____________________________________________________________________________//

test_suite*
init_unit_test_suite( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    const auto testSuite1Id = framework::master_test_suite().get("test_suite1");

    if( testSuite1Id != INV_TEST_UNIT_ID ) {
        auto test_suite1 = &framework::get<test_suite>( testSuite1Id );

        const auto testSuite2Id = framework::master_test_suite().get("test_suite2");
        if (testSuite2Id != INV_TEST_UNIT_ID) {
            auto testSuite2 = &framework::get<test_suite>( testSuite2Id );

            const auto testCase4Id = testSuite2->get("test_case4");
            if (testCase4Id != INV_TEST_UNIT_ID) {
                // test_suite1 depends on test_suite2/test_case4 
                test_suite1->depends_on( &framework::get<test_case>( testCase4Id ));
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Running 3 test cases...
Entering test suite "Master Test Suite"
Entering test suite "test_suite2"
Entering test case "test_case4"
<blahblahblah>/consoleapplication5/consoleapplication5.cpp(10): error in "test_case4": check false failed
Leaving test case "test_case4"; testing time: 14ms
Leaving test suite "test_suite2"
Test suite "test_suite1"is skipped
Leaving test suite "Master Test Suite"

*** 1 failure detected in test suite "Master Test Suite"
```

Comment: Thanks for providing concrete syntax.  I had assumed that since the issue was brought up ~3 years ago that the documentation would've been fixed by now, but it seems that is not the case.

You mentioned "BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE" in your answer, so I'd like to ask: is there any way of invoking the "depends_on" functionality from test cases submitted via automated registration in Boost?  If not, I found a library called NCBI that supports the macro syntax that will probably work to support test dependencies.

Comment: Updated answer with registration for auto test cases and suites.

Comment: Note that nonetheless, the tests will not be executed in dependency order. If you declared test_suite1 first, it will be skipped because test_case4 "failed" because it didn't run yet.

Answer (score 3):

Starting on Boost 1.59 you have better tools for this: `depends_on`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/test_org_reference/decorator_depends_on.html

Usage is pretty simple (from Boost docu):

```
namespace utf = boost::unit_test;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test3, * utf::depends_on("s1/test1"))
{
  BOOST_TEST(false);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test4, * utf::depends_on("test3"))
{
  BOOST_TEST(false);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(s1)

  BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test1)
  {
    BOOST_TEST(true);
  }

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```